# What would be the time complexity and Big-0 of this pseudo code?

Tags: for-loop, time-complexity, big-o, pseudocode

Algorithm `squareRoot (k)`

Approximates the square root of k using the "Babylonian Method".

```
pre: k is an integer

returns: approximation of square root of k 
1:    guess ← 1.0                                   // ??

2:    for i from 0 to i<=100 do                     //??

3:       guess ← (guess + k/guess) / 2.0             //??

4:    done                                          // This has no running time of course

f(n)= ?
O(?)
```

Comment: There's no `n` in the program, so it's O(1) by definition, always doing 101 iteration.

Comment: 1: guess ← 1.0                           // 1 time

2: for i from 0 to i<=100 do         // 101 times

3: guess ← (guess + k/guess) / 2.0       // 1 time

4: done // This has no running time of course

f(n)=  1+ 101 *(1)  is this correct to say? and O(1) = constant time?  Is  my formula correct?

Comment: `1 + 101 * (1)` looks like the correct overview, yeah. Still, it may be the case that something is amiss with the question itself, for example, `100` is actually meant to be `n`.